# Angular 4 recuperar parámetros URL

Tags: sql, angular4

He probado a usar:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
  params => {
    this.params = params;
  }
);
```

La función la uso en el constructor y cada vez que los valores de los parámetros cambian los recupera correctamente. El problema es que quiero obtener los parámetros iniciales (los que aparece en la url que el usuario introduce en el navegador) pero de mano siempre devuelve un objeto vacío sin importar si la URL lleva o no parámetros.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de los parámetros que quieres capturar?

Comment: por ejemplo www.dominio.com?page=2 para obtener el parámetro page

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago así:

```
private sub: any;
private paramNum: number;
private paramTxt: string;

ngOnInit() {    
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.paramNum = +params['num']; // Importante el '+' para obtener números
    this.paramTxt = params['txt'];
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Sobre el guardar la "suscripción" en una variable, entiendo que es para mantener los datos. Lo vi siguiendo los tutoriales de Angular y lo hacían de esta manera, a mí me funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he podido entender es un comportamiento normal que obtenga un objeto vacío porque se trata de una subscripción y hasta que no cambie el valor no obtendré los nuevos.

Por ello para obtener los valores iniciales he usado la siguiente función:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
  params => {
    this.params = params;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar la función en el método ngOnInit:

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            let page = params['page'];
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146396/9209251